# Any function to encode unicode characters to "A-Z0-9" for SVG format and can be decoded by major browsers?

Tags: svg, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, decode

The given raw text are in unicode, and contains many languages, Germany, English, Chinese, and special characters, like comma, double quote, single quote, and etc.

Is there any function to encode these unicode words into "A-Z0-9" characters? They are in an SVG file, I wish that majoy browsers have a standard function to decode them. Any tips would be appreciated.

> Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is an XML-based vector image format for
>   two-dimensional graphics with support for interactivity and animation.
>   The SVG specification is an open standard developed by the World Wide
>   Web Consortium (W3C) since 1999. SVG images and their behaviors are
>   defined in XML text files.

EDIT:

I have a need to convert unicode characters to "A-Z0-9" only, because this file was generated from another python code. And special characters like '," are reserved and have special meanings in Python. I need to convert these characters first.

Comment: You mean charCodeAt in javascript? Your question is not very clear. Try adding some examples/code to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need to encode / decode your characters. You could just use unicode characters and save the svg as UTF-8. See [this answer](/a/5834630/4235784) for an explanation and an example.

Comment: Is `<string>`.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace") what you want?